# Should I use std::vector + my own size variable or not?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Note: Performance is very critical in my application!
Allocate enough buffer storage for the worst case scenario is a requirement to avoid reallocation.

Look at this, this is how I usually use std::vector:

```
//On startup...
unsigned int currVectorSize = 0u;
std::vector<MyStruct> myStructs;
myStructs.resize(...); //Allocate for the worst case scenario!

//Each frame, do this.
currVectorSize = 0u; //Reset vector, very fast.

run algorithm...
//insert X elements in myStructs if condition is met
myStructs[currVectorSize].member0 = ;
myStructs[currVectorSize].member1 = ;
myStructs[currVectorSize].member2 = ;
currVectorSize++;

run another algorithm...
//insert X elements in myStructs if condition is met
myStructs[currVectorSize].member0 = ;
myStructs[currVectorSize].member1 = ;
myStructs[currVectorSize].member2 = ;
currVectorSize++;

Another part of the application uses myStructs and currVectorSize
```

I have a decision problem, should I use std::vector + resize + my own size variable OR std::vector + reserve + push_back + clear + size?

I don't like to keep another size variable floating around, but the clear() function is slow(linear time) and the push_back function have the overhead of bounds check. I need to reset the size variable in constant time each frame without calling any destructors and running in linear time.
Conclusion: I don't want to destroy my old data, I just need to reset the current size/current number inserted elements variable each frame.

Comment: `clear()` should be constant time if your objects are trivially destructible. It sounds like you already know what would be most performant (though be sure to profile it!), so if you're optimizing for speed/performance, you already know what your answer is.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the best way to do it for this specific case. About the clear function: yes, it should be constant for POD-types, but different compilers... you don't know...

Comment: reserve + push_back + is_trivially_destructible must be true + maybe allow overcommit memory which you can allow system wide on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is critical, then perhaps you should just profile everything you can.

Using your own size variable can help if you can be sure that no reallocation is needed beforehand (this is what you do - incrementing `currVectorSize` with no checks), but in this case why use `std::vector` at all? Just use an array or `std::array`.

Otherwise (if reallocation could happen) you would still need to compare your size variable to actual vector size, so this will be pretty much the same thing `push_back` does and will gain you nothing.

There are also some tweaked/optimized implementations of `vector` like `folly::fbvector` but you should carefully consider (and again, profile) wheter or not you need something like that.

As for clearing the vector, check out `vector::resize` - it is actually guaranteed not to reallocate if you're resizing down (due to iterator invalidation). So you can call `resize(0)` instead of `clear` just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, reallocation will never happen in my application. I will probably use std::array instead of std::vector, thanks for the advice.